# What contributions has PPCG made to the fields of math or computer science?

Tags: discussion

Most of the content on PPCG involves clever applications of existing algorithms, or just-fast-enough-to-pass solutions to problems that supercomputers have found millions of answers/digits/etc to already. However, somewhere among all of the brainpower we spend on these challenges, surely someone has come up with something truly original.

Possible examples:

- a new good algorithm for a known problem
- establishing a new lower or upper bound for some value or some algorithm's runtime
- extending an existing OEIS sequence beyond previous computation

Where are those things?

Comment: While not specifically maths or science related I believe those who post challenges get better at designing a technical brief.

Comment: [Cited as reference [22] in a paper co-authored by Aaronson—does that count?](http://www.scottaaronson.com/busybeaver.pdf)

Comment: @wchargin for now the bar is pretty low, given that we've got just a dozen or so examples. Go ahead and add that to the "Appearances in papers and articles" answer.

Answer (score 43):

## Contributions to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/)

Please edit all OEIS-only contributions into this post, instead of posting a separate answer for each. If there's a larger result that also led to an OEIS contribution (like a novel algorithm that allowed computation of more terms), feel free to post it separately, though.

- **[A005434](https://oeis.org/A005434)**: [Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39242/anders-kaseorg) wrote a fast program to calculate this sequence using the method described in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(81)90038-8), and E-Hern Lee ([ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only)) submitted a b-list with 654 terms.
- **[A049064](https://oeis.org/A049064)**: Kade Robertson ([Shebang](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38417/shebang)) extended the sequence, and created [A259710](https://oeis.org/A259710) for the base-10 representation of the sequence.
- **[A066931](https://oeis.org/A066931)**: [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) [challenged](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51266/194) PPCG to extend the sequence; [Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) found a formula and updated it with more terms. As a side-effect he also improved **[A049503](https://oeis.org/A049503)** and submitted **[A259049](https://oeis.org/A259049)**.
- **[A162171](https://oeis.org/A162171)**: Mike Tryczak ([primo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4098/primo)) corrected and extended the sequence, and added a conjectured formula. The mistake was spotted while working on [Computing truncated digits sums of powers of pi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48202/4098).
- **[A169683](https://oeis.org/A169683)**: The entry used to be based entirely on the page numbers in the xkcd book. [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) added the proper definition of the sequence, some comments, references, more terms and a Mathematica program.
- **[A181018](https://oeis.org/A181018)** and **[A181019](https://oeis.org/A181019)**: [Tic-tac-toe with only crosses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68678/194) brought A181018 to [Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor)'s attention, and he was surprised to see that no-one seemed to have applied dynamic programming to its computation. He extended A181018 by 4 terms, and its generalisation A181019 by 276 terms.
- **[A201168](https://oeis.org/A201168)**: [Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) discovered a mistake in the comments of this sequence while searching for sequences to be used for [Evolution of OEIS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49223/8478). He proposed a correction and subsequently extended the sequence by several terms and included a Mathematica program.
- **[A256504](https://oeis.org/A256504)**: [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) corrected a typo in the explanation (along with a mistake in the sequence [pointed out by mathmandan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50845/fissile-numbers#comment120433_50845)) while also adding more terms and a Mathematica program.
- **[A263172](https://oeis.org/A263172)**: Matthew McCaskill ([GamrCorps](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36670/gamrcorps)) submitted the [Dennis numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57719/generate-dennis-numbers) (coined by [Calvin's Hobbies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26997/calvins-hobbies)) after a four month process to get them approved. On the page it has several references to PPCG.SE, as well as a golfed program.
- **[A263542](https://oeis.org/A263542)**: [Doorknob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3808/doorknob) wondered if there were any 3x3 squares of numbers where every 2x2 sub-square had the same sum, which were subsequently termed "[sturdy squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61430/12914)". Multiple people worked on calculating the terms in this sequence, including [Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21487/sp3000), [flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr), [El'endia Starman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12914/elendia-starman), and especially [Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) (and any others I forgot). El'endia submitted the sequence to OEIS and it was approved after almost a month.
- **[A268754](https://oeis.org/A268754)**: [El'endia Starman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12914/elendia-starman) was playing around with 1-by-N oscillators in a particular Life-like rule, and came up with a sequence that resisted initial efforts at cracking it. Thus, [a challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71970/12914), [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35699) (frozen and deleted automatically), and an entry on OEIS (submitted by El'endia) were spawned. [orlp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4162/orlp) did most of the work of calculating the terms.
- **[A288793](https://oeis.org/A288793)**: E-Hern Lee ([ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only)) submitted this sequence after a [PPCG question to calculate its terms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124424/finding-approximate-correlations).
- **[A290151](https://oeis.org/A290151)**: Eamon Olive ([Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)) submitted this sequence after a [PPCG question to calculate its terms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/133747/194).
- **[A334875](https://oeis.org/A334875)**: Jonathan Oswald ([Lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal)) submitted this sequence after a [question to calculate its terms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/204669/78410).
- **[A334617](https://oeis.org/A334617)**: [Peter Kagey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53884/peter-kagey) submitted this sequence after a [question to calculate its terms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/210748/78410).
- **[A346232](https://oeis.org/A346232)** and **[A346693](https://oeis.org/A346693)**: [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo) submitted these sequences after a [question to calculate the terms of the first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231176/maximum-number-of-squares-touched-by-a-line-segment), in which [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) found a very neat formula. The second sequence is the "pseudo-inverse" of the first.
- **[A059757](https://oeis.org/A059757)**: [Peter Kagey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53884/peter-kagey), on behalf of [xash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95594/xash), extended and corrected the sequence after a [question to calculate its terms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/230509/66833). The sequence was extended first by [xash's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230542/66833) from \$n \le 13\$ to \$n \le 162\$, then up to \$n \le 538\$ by [Nick Kennedy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230797/66833).
- **[A350418](https://oeis.org/A350418)**: Woosuk Kwak ([Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)) challenged CGCC to calculate the fourth term of this sequence with a +500 bounty. [AnttiP](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/84290/anttip) [calculated](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240339/counting-universal-n-ary-logic-gates/240341#240341) it and corrected a previous result (n=3), allowing Kwak to submit the sequence.

Answer (score 27):

## Appearances in papers and articles

Here's a few works which reference PPCG in some way or other:

- *[N queens problem: a metaprogramming stress test for the compiler](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2502492)* (2013): An article citing [Solve the eight queens problem at compile-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/solve-the-eight-queens-problem-at-compile-time) under "Previous work".
- *[No Code: Null Programs](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/87669)* (2014): A technical report on 0 byte programs. References [Random832's wc answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2945/21487) to "Write a program to print the sum of the ascii codes of the program"
- *[Threes!, Fives, 1024!, and 2048 are Hard](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04274)* (2015): An arXiv paper on the computational complexity of 2048 and related games. References [Claudiu's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24885/solve-a-deterministic-version-of-2048-using-the-fewest-bytes) to "Solve a deterministic version of 2048 using the fewest bytes" by noting that the highest value on a 4x4 board is still unknown.
- *[A Relatively Small Turing Machine Whose Behavior Is Independent of Set Theory](http://www.scottaaronson.com/busybeaver.pdf)* ([2015](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/100680) / 2016): A paper demonstrating the existence of a 7918-state Turing machine that cannot be proven to run forever in ZFC. Cites PPCG as "A place where programmers go for recreational code golfing".
- *[Un reloj digital programado en el Juego de la vida](http://www.microsiervos.com/archivo/ordenadores/reloj-digital-juego-de-la-vida.html)*: In English, the title is "A digital clock programmed in the Game of Life". It is a news article about [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111932/64159).

And finally,

- *[Testing and benchmarking the prototype MRuby compiler](http://eprints.fri.uni-lj.si/2351/)* (2014): A thesis citing [Generate a mandelbrot fractal?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/generate-a-mandelbrot-fractal). I can't read this, but I do believe that they are trying to cite the *image* in the Mandelbrot section. If so, then that's one undeserved citation for us, since Wikipedia dates this image [back to 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set).
- *[Expert JavaScript](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=MPBZAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&dq=codegolf.stackexchange&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMI97mDm5rHxwIVxuamCh2Hig5X#v=onepage&q=codegolf.stackexchange&f=false)* (2013): A book which has [Tips for golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) in its references for the "Jargon and Slang" chapter.

Answer (score 7):

## Papers or technical documents originated by a challenge

This includes papers or documents about problems proposed in a PPCG challenge, or directly derived from it.

- [*On the number of tiles visited by a line segment on a rectangular grid*](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1112/mtk.12223) (*Mathematika*, vol. 69, no. 4, October 2023), by [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) and [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo). Originated from [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/231176/maximum-number-of-squares-touched-by-a-line-segment).